# In schema registry, consumer's schema could differ from the producer's, what actually it means

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

While producing AVRO data to Kafka, Avro serializer writing the same schema ID in the byte array which is used while writing the data.

Kafka Consumer fetches the schema from Schema Registry based on schema ID in the byte array received. So same schema ID is used in both i.e. Producer and Consumer and so the schema.

But why many article including this [one](https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-avro-serialization-and-the-schema-registry) says *The consumer's schema could differ from the producer's.*

Please help me in understanding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Kafka Consumer fetches the schema from Schema Registry based on schema ID

Only if you let the deserializer do that.

You're capable of defining your own, compatible schema in the consumer code. Therefore, it *could be different* and follows the rules of Avro schema evolution

> schema evolution happens only during deserialization at the consumer (read). If the consumer’s schema is different from the producer’s schema, then the value or key is automatically modified during deserialization to conform to the consumer's read schema if possible.

Comment: That means if I customize the Kafka Avro Deserializer by attaching(using) a different schema from what we received in the ID of byte array, then followinng sentence will apply. ""value or key is automatically modified during deserialization to conform to the consumer's read schema"".

Again we are ignoring the ID received in the byte array.

Comment: You wouldn't be customizing it since that feature already exists. The `KafkaConsumer<K, V>` class accepts arbitrary class types. But yes, the ID would be ignored if a custom schema is provided. It's up to the consumer to ensure that schema applies to the bytes in the message, of course.

Comment: Ok I got it thanks. I can have different 'V' in Producer and consumer. @cricket_007 Thanks for help!