# Why Apache Kafka consumer would use a different version of schema to deserialize record other than the one sent along with the data?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

Let us assume I am using Avro serialization while sending data to kafka.

While consuming record from Apache Kafka, I get both the schema and the record. I can use the schema to parse the record. I am not getting the scenario why consumer would use a different version of schema to deserialize the record. Can someone help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52356783/in-schema-registry-consumers-schema-could-differ-from-the-producers-what-act is one answer I found. If anyone has some other thoughts please do share.

Answer (score 0):

The message is serialized with the the unique id for a specific version of the schema when produced onto Kafka. The consumer would use that unique schema id to deserialize.

Taken from https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/avro.html#schema-evolution

Comment: True. I understand this. But I am trying to understand when the consumer will use a different version of the schema? To put in other words, why do I need schema evolution when kafka message has schema id and consumer can use it to deserialize it. I know I am missing something. But not getting what it is.

Comment: If you change the schema e.g. add a field, when pushed to the Schema Registry will generate a new id. This allows Consumer A to consume schema version 1 but will not get the new field (which is okay for this consumer). Consumer B meanwhile wants to deserialize messages with version 2 to get the new field. As you can see, different consumers can make decisions on whether they need to use the latest schema or evolve later.